# MySQL - Update date/time - 10 mins. in future

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to update date/time in MySQL directly.

```
UPDATE tasks SET date_due='2014-12-01 10:30:00' WHERE  tasks.id = '97534f55-32a9-8ef3-2e2f-547c3782d5e6' AND deleted=0;
```

I need to update time, 10 mins. in future.

The said time is **not current time** therefore I cannot use DATE_ADD(NOW()

Thanx

Comment: Maybe step away from the keyboard, have a cup of coffee, and then come back to it.

Comment: But you *can* use `DATE_ADD(date_due, ...)`?

Comment: You can update it directly from phpmyadmin or by providing time in proper format in updatequer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `date_add()` on a datetime value not just `now()`

```
mysql> select date_add('2014-12-01 10:30:00',interval 10 minute) as date ;
+---------------------+
| date                |
+---------------------+
| 2014-12-01 10:40:00 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

So it will be

```
UPDATE 
tasks 
SET date_due=date_add(date_due,interval 10 minute) 
WHERE  tasks.id = '97534f55-32a9-8ef3-2e2f-547c3782d5e6' 
AND deleted=0;
```